# Hibernate: Save the reference if it does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, merge

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {
  @Column
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn...
  private ClassB classB;
  public ClassA(ClassB classB){
    this.classB = classB;
  }
  //....
  //....
}

@Entity
public class ClassB {
  @Column
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique=true) //important
  private String name;
  public ClassB(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  //....
  //....
}
```

I want to save `ClassA` and save `ClassB` only if `ClassB` does not exist yet.

```
ClassB b = new ClassB("myName");
ClassA a = new ClassA(b);
session.merge(a); // fine
ClassA a2 = new ClassA(b);
session.merge(a2); // problem with b
```

Ofcourse I can check `ClassB` if it exists and load it but I want to do it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

if classB exists and classB is managed,then getEntityManager.contains(b) returns true.

```
ClassB b = new ClassB("myName");

    if(getEntityManager.contains(b)){
   ClassA a = new ClassA(b)
    session.merge(a);
    }
   else{
    session.merge(b);
    ClassA a = new ClassA(b)
    session.merge(b);
     }
```

Comment: `contains(obj)` only tests if the object exists in the current session, or in EntityManager speak, *the current persistence context*. It won't query the database to see if the object with that ID already exists. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Why do you firstly save ClassB.if saving is successful,then you can create ClassA with ClassB as parameter and save ClassA.this is my idea.Maybe helps you.

Comment: I thought that this will works: `ClassB b = hibernateSession.merge(new ClassB("myName")); hibernateSession.merge(new ClassA(b));` but it doesn't. Any other better ideas? :)